# php or javascript: Allow text to appear on specific page only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a text that is appearing on every single page of my website, I need a way to hide it from all pages except from one.

Let us say I need it to appear on the page 1, but don't want it appearing on page 2, page 3, page 4...

Something like:

if

current page is page 1

then

show text on page 1

else

Hide text from other pages

end of function

EDIT:

I need that for my SEO, I hired a company to make my website' SEO and they asked for an onpage optimization, I included the text in the page they asked, but now the text appears on every single page of one of the site's areas.

EDIT 2:

As requested, here is the code I'm applying, with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var pages = window.location.href;    
if(pages == "sitedotcom/page1"){

Text 1.

    //display page 1 text
}
else if(pages == ""){


Text 2.
    //display page 2 text
}

</script
```

**THE SOLUTION**

[How can I insert HTML text in Javascript the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685846/how-can-i-insert-html-text-in-javascript-the-right-way)

Comment: You can do that in PHP using $_SERVER variable you can fetch file name and do whatever you want from it.

Comment: Do you have a seperate files for each page ? Do you layout ?

Comment: Show us your code that now includes it on each page.

Comment: Make sure you put the url in the else if statement as well.  Since it doesn't know what argument to look for, it won't perform correctly.  Also, make sure you include the complete filename.  If page1 is and html file, be sure to put .html behind it.  Same goes for php files.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a file name. If I insert the same url in the "else if", won't it cause a conflict?

Comment: By the way, is this jQuery?

Comment: I don't get it why don't you just add the text on page1.php and not on all the others.. Can you provide the PHP code that adds this text everywhere? This is the cause of the problem..it should be acting only in one file or be in one file..

Comment: I mustn't hack the code, as this script gets updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in both PHP and Javascript as referenced in the other answers.  However, it's much more efficient to do it in Javascript, especially if your text is static to each HTML page.  For instance, something similar to this should work:

```
var pages = window.location.href;    
if(pages == "page1"){
    //display page 1 text
}
else if(pages == "page2"){
    //display page 2 text
}
etc...
etc...
```

This is a very simple way to do this with Javascript.

Comment: Yes.  The page numbers in the if statement are where you place your URLs.  So where "page1" is, you place your url.

Comment: Sorry, it's Javascript.

Comment: yay! Thx, I'll give it a try and tell you if it worked.

Comment: OK.  If it does, don't forget to accept the answer.  If it doesn't, let me know and I can try to help you more.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It's just this code inside <script> tags, right?

Comment: Yes.  Also, with this method, you need to place the text within the body of your if/else statement.  If it's possible, could you possibly ad some code to your question to kind of give us some reference to better help you?

Comment: Sure I can, just a minute.

Comment: Is this jQuery? I'm even trying similar codes on jsfiddle, no success.
http://jsfiddle.net/zv236zwx/3/

Comment: It can be vanilla Javascript or jQuery.  The if statements are the same.

Comment: Why do you have this line in your code:

`url.toLowerCase().indexOf`

?

Comment: oh, sorry, that's another code. I'll provide you with your code, just a sec.

Comment: There are actually a couple things wrong with your fiddle.  In the if/else statement, you're checking for the same URL so it's not going to know which block to run.  Also, you're not writing/appending anything to any HTML so nothing's going to show up when you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER[PHP_SELF] == "page1.php") {

}
```

Comment: can I change page1.php for the URL?

E.g.:
if ($_SERVER[PHP_SELF] == "http://sitedotcom/page1") {

}

Comment: @Matt why do you need the URL?

Comment: Because it's a wordpress site, I can't specify according to file.

Comment: if ("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" == "sitedotcom/page1") {

}

?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == 'page1.php'){ 
    echo "message goes here";
}
```

Haven't tested it, but that should work